# PowerBI - Table and Dax Formula

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm kind of stuck right now and wondering why my table does not show the data for January 2023 or any past year. Note: please dont mind the spelling of "Separation" as "Seperation". our HRIS is the one to fault :D

[This is filtered for fiscal year of 2024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5f6V.png)

[This is filtered for fiscal year of 2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NJH4.png)

Here is my formula for YTD Attrition and Ann Attrition

```
YTD Attrition = 
DIVIDE([Total Separations], ([Opening HC April] + [Closing HC]) / 2, 0)


Total Separations = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTX (
        FILTER (
            'Separations',
            'Separations'[Effective Date of Seperation] >= CALCULATE(DATE(YEAR(MAX('Date'[Date])), 4, 1)) &&
            'Separations'[Effective Date of Seperation] <= CALCULATE(MAXX(VALUES('Date'[Year]), MAX('Date'[Date])))
        ),
        'Separations'[Local Emp ID]
    ),
    CROSSFILTER('Separations'[Effective Date of Seperation], 'Date'[Date], None)
)

Opening HC April = 
VAR _min_date = MINX(ALL('Date'), 'Date'[Date])

VAR _Expression =
    IF (
        ISFILTERED('Date'[Month Year]),
        MAXX('Date', ENDOFMONTH(DATEADD('Date'[Date], 3 - MONTH('Date'[Date]), MONTH))),
        MAXX('Date', DATEADD('Date'[Date], -1, YEAR))
    )

RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTX (
            FILTER (
                'Employee List',
                'Employee List'[Join Date] <= CALCULATE(_Expression) &&
                'Employee List'[Join Date] >= _min_date &&
                (ISBLANK('Employee List'[Effective Date of Seperation]) || 'Employee List'[Effective Date of Seperation] > CALCULATE(_Expression))
            ),
            'Employee List'[Local Emp ID]
        ),
        CROSSFILTER('Employee List'[Join Date], 'Date'[Date], None)
    )


Closing HC = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTX(
        FILTER(
            'Employee List',
            'Employee List'[Join Date] <= CALCULATE(MAXX(VALUES('Date'[Year]), MAX('Date'[Date]))) &&
            (ISBLANK('Employee List'[Effective Date of Seperation])) || 'Employee List'[Effective Date of Seperation] > CALCULATE(MAXX(VALUES('Date'[Year]), MAX('Date'[Date])))
        ),
        'Employee List'[Local Emp ID]
    ),
    CROSSFILTER('Employee List'[Join Date], 'Date'[Date], None)
)



Ann Attrition = 
VAR ReportingMonth = MAX('Date'[Fiscal Month No])
RETURN
    [YTD Attrition] * (12 / ReportingMonth)
```

I'm only relying on what i got from chat GPT. I know that AI will not always give you the correct answer but this is the only source that i have and i'm totally noob on DAX. i just used my experience in coding vb.net and VBA